# Why am I not receiving log INFO messages in python?

Tags: python, logging, command-line

So I'm running the following code from the command line python:

```
import logging

rootLog = logging.getLogger(__name__)
rootLog.setLevel(logging.INFO)
rootLog.warning("This is a root warning")
rootLog.info("This is root info")
def info():
    log = rootLog.getChild("info")
    log.info("This is info")
    log.warning("This is a warning")
info()
```

I'm expecting to see all four log messages on the console, but I'm only seeing the warnings.  What is going on?  Am I misunderstanding something?

EDIT:

I discovered by adding logging.basicConfig() at the beginning of the script that I'll get the output that I expected.  This is strange, because the python documentation on logging states:

> The functions `debug()`, `info()`, `warning()`, `error()` and `critical()` will call `basicConfig()` automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger.

Comment: What handlers do you have attached?  If memory serves, handlers can filter by log level as well.

Comment: The code above is the only code running, so I guess none.  See my edit though.

Comment: Just an FYI, you do know that strictly speaking, your `rootLogger` is not the true root logger, right?

Comment: Yeah, I realize my naming convention is a little inaccurate as far as python is concerned, but it was good enough for my testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit you quote from the manual is under [Module-Level Functions](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#module-level-functions) and applies only if the module function

```
 logging.debug()
```

is literally called. Since you are calling an instance method with `rootLog.info()` basicConfig isn't getting called for you and you are probably talking to a null logger. The documentation is kinda confusing there.

Use `loggging.basicConfig()` and things should work.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I dug through the code in the logging module, and I think I figured it out, at least partially.  What you are seeing is happening because what you are calling `rootLogger` isn't actually the root logger.  It is true that if no handlers have been added to the root logger (the true root logger) when you call one of the log methods directly on `logging`, it calls `basicConfig`, but calling a log method on an instance of `Logger` as you are doing here does not actually call `basicConfig` at all.  That's actually irrelevant in this case anyway though.  :)  I'm not sure where the handler that is getting called here is being created, but I can almost guarantee it's attached to the true root logger.  The true root logger is initialized by default to `WARNING`.  Try doing `logging.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)` and see if you get what you expect.  You should also see what you want if you manually attach a logger to your `rootLogger`.